# How to programmatically print without prompting for filename in MFC and CView using Print-To-PDF printer?

Tags: c++, pdf, printing, mfc

I have a large graphics program using C++, MFC, and C++6.0. 
I need it to print to PDFs without prompting the user for printer settings and file name.

I use `CView::OnPrint()` to print using Microsoft Print-to-PDF and it works fine except for the user prompts.

I've seen how to bypass those prompts with a `PrintDocument` object in C# but how can I do that when using `CView::OnPrint()` in MFC? Surely there must be a way?

My project is much too big to consider re-writing in C#, and I've tried moving forward to Visual studio 2005/2010/2019 etc. without success as changes in default data structure packing and converting existing data files is fraught with problems so solution has to be an addition to existing MFC C++6.0 if at all possible.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This is why I prefer not to use MFC and instead use wxWidgets.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used VC++ 6 in quite a while now, so I'm going from rather distant memories, but the general idea is fairly simple.

#### Full Approach

Your view has a `DoPreparePrinting` member function. By default, this creates a `CPrintDialog` object, then invokes the `CPrintDialog`'s `DoModal` to show the print settings dialog. Eventually (but not in `DoPreparePrinting`, if memory serves) that `CPrinterDialog`'s `CreatePrinterDC` will be called to (obviously enough) create a DC for the printer using the settings the user entered in the dialog.

To bypass the dialog, you can override `DoPreparePrinting`. That receives a pointer to a `CPrintDialog`. Since you don't want to show a print dialog, you obviously *won't* invoke its `DoModal` member. Instead, you'll fill in its `DEVMODE` and `DEVNAMES` structures for the printer and any settings you want. Then when `CreatePrinterDC` gets called, it'll use what you filled in without displaying the dialog.

My personal advice would be to do a run using the dialog under the debugger, then after the `CPrintDialog`'s `DoModal` has returned, look through the `DEVNAMES` structure it returned. You may not need it, but I found the `DEVNAMES` structure a little confusing the first time I had to set it up on my own. The `DEVMODE` is bigger and arguably more complex, but I've usually just modified a few bits and pieces, and left most of it with default values.

#### Simplified Approach

If you just want to use the system's default print settings, there's a simpler approach: you can override `OnPreparePrinting`. This receives a `pInfo` parameter, which is a pointer to a `CPrintInfo`. That has an `m_bDirect` member, which you can set to `true` to do "direct" printing, which just uses the default settings without using a printer dialog. I don't remember for sure when m_bDirect was added though. If it's missing, there's a "trick" to get the same effect: the default implementation of `DoPreparePrinting` doesn't display a print dialog for a print preview, so you override `OnPreparePrinting` to set `m_bPreview` to true, invoke `DoPreparePrinting`, then set `m_bPreview` back to `false`.

Comment: You also want to set `lpszOutput` in `DOCINFO` to let it know what the PDF file name is.